# Sign out of all tabs if logged out from one - Angular 11& Storage Events I am using cookie for token

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M34lG.png)

Sign out of all tabs if logged out from one tab

I am set token using cookie set and logout the clear the cookies data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to add window event? try this:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
  if (event.storageArea == localStorage) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('jwt_token');
    if(token == undefined) { // you can update this as per your key
        // DO LOGOUT FROM THIS TAB AS WELL
        this.router.navigate(['/']); // If you are using router
        // OR
        window.location.href = '<home page URL>';
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am using cookie